# IDA Signatures for OpenSSL

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, cryptography, flirt-signatures

This may be an old topic, but I still haven't find a solution. Sometimes happens to reverse Windows executables that contain strings clearly related to encryption algorithms implemented through OpenSSL. For the ones who are familiar, sometimes is even possible to identify which version of OpenSSL implements these algorithms (example string: RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.7 31 Dec 2002).

IDA Pro seems unable to identify such functions as library function and this complicates the analysis because you can't distinguish between interesting code and OpenSSL library code.

Is anyone aware about FLIRT signatures or IDA scripts that can ease this job?

Comment: Duplicate of [Mapping an external module's source code to assembly - extracting information from source code](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3222/1562)